# Android CoordinatorLayout with AppbarLayout Double Fling Bug

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

AppbarLayout has a big child, so we can drag and fling it.

It goes wrong when I fling appbar with its child first and fling scrollview **before** previous fling animation is **finished**.

**The scrolling then became a mess when double flinging occured on both appbar and nestedscrollview**

Here is the layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior"
        >
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:background="#8f8"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:background="#88f" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with `RecyclerView`

[image: Double Fling Bug]

See `HeaderViewBehavior.setHeaderTopBottomOffset`, it's invoked with different directions for `newOffset` parameter.
You should cancel `AppBarLayout.Behavior` fling when `onStartNestedScroll` invoked.

**How to fix:**

Override `AppBarLayout.Behavior`

```kotlin
package com.google.android.material.appbar // original package

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.widget.OverScroller
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

class FixFlingBehavior @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null
) : AppBarLayout.Behavior(context, attributeSet) {

    private var isAppbarFlinging: Boolean = false
    private var originalScroller: OverScroller? = null
    private val fakeScroller: OverScroller = object : OverScroller(context) {
        override fun computeScrollOffset(): Boolean {
            scroller = originalScroller
            return false // it cancels HeaderBehavior FlingRunnable
        }
    }

    override fun setHeaderTopBottomOffset(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, newOffset: Int, minOffset: Int, maxOffset: Int): Int {
        isAppbarFlinging = minOffset == Int.MIN_VALUE && maxOffset == Int.MAX_VALUE
        if (scroller === fakeScroller) {
            scroller = originalScroller
        }
        return super.setHeaderTopBottomOffset(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, newOffset, minOffset, maxOffset)
    }

    override fun onFlingFinished(parent: CoordinatorLayout, layout: AppBarLayout) {
        super.onFlingFinished(parent, layout)
        isAppbarFlinging = false
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: AppBarLayout, directTargetChild: View, target: View, nestedScrollAxes: Int, type: Int): Boolean {
        if (isAppbarFlinging && scroller !== fakeScroller) {
            originalScroller = scroller
            scroller = fakeScroller
        }
        return super.onStartNestedScroll(parent, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes, type)
    }
}
```

And use it in your layout

```xml
...
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.FixFlingBehavior">
...
```